# Cyclic property of trace over a ring

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

If $R$ is an arbitrary ring, non necessarily commutative, does the cyclic property of the trace still hold for matrices over this ring. What conditions on the ring would make it hold?

Comment: I assume that by the "cyclic property", you mean $tr(AB) = tr(BA).$ If there are no restrictions on the dimensions of the matrices under consideration, we can consider one-by-one matrices. For such matrices, the cyclic property of the trace holds (for all one-by-one matrices) iff $R$ is commutative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we are given an arbitrary ring $R.$ Let's fix an $n\in\mathbb N$ and assume that the following holds.
$$
\forall A,B\in R^{n\times n}:tr(AB) = tr(BA)\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad(*)
$$
For an arbitrary $a\in R,$ denote by $E_{11}(a)\in R^{n\times n}$ the matrix all of whose entries are $0$ **except** the top left entry (i.e. with indices $(1,1)$), which is $a$. A quick calculation shows that, for arbitrary $a,b\in R,$ we have
$$
E_{11}(a)E_{11}(b) = E_{11}(ab).
$$
Using this and $(*),$ we find
$$
ab = tr(E_{11}(ab)) = tr(E_{11}(a)E_{11}(b)) = tr(E_{11}(b)E_{11}(a)) = tr(E_{11}(ba)) = ba.
$$
Since $a$ and $b$ were arbitrary, we conclude that $R$ must be commutative.

So we have shown that commutativity of $R$ is equivalent to the cyclic property of the trace. More specifically: (there exists an $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $(*)$ holds) iff ($R$ is commutative).